# ByteBuffer convert Bitmap crash

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

Hi I wanna convert byte array to bitmap and show image in a ImageView. I wrote the following code but I got exception that says that the buffer not large enough for pixels.

```
Image resolution : 480*640
ARGB = 480*640\*4 = 1228800????
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(480,640, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
byte[] temp = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,745488,1228800);
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(temp);
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels at
> android.graphics.Bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(Bitmap.java:567) at
> com.example.scratch.HomeActivity$3.run(HomeActivity.java:119) at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121) at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)

Comment: What do you think `Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes,745488,1228800);` is returning? Since your image has 307200 pixels at 32 bit is requires 1228800 bytes. Now you're creating a byte array of 483312 bytes - why? do you realize why "Buffer not large enough" is being reported if you provide that array as the input?

Comment: I misread the parameters, I thought the third parameter was the length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android/Java:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.blendmode);
        app = (MessiApplication) this.getApplication();
        blendModeRawStreamBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(app.getVideoWidth(),app.getVideoHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        blendModeColorStreamBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(app.getVideoWidth(),app.getVideoHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        blendModeRawStreamImageView = findViewById(R.id.blend_mode_raw_video_view_id);
        blendModeColorStreamImageView = findViewById(R.id.blend_mode_color_video_view_id);
        videoStreamInfo = new VideoStreamInfo(app.getVideoWidth() , app.getVideoHeight(), app.getRawPseudoOffset(), 0);
    }

    private int _onAllVideoFrame(int cmd, String [] path, byte[] rawBytes, byte[] colorBytes)
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ByteBuffer rawStreamBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(rawBytes);
                blendModeRawStreamBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(rawStreamBuffer);
                blendModeRawStreamImageView.setImageBitmap(blendModeRawStreamBitmap);

                ByteBuffer colorStreamBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(colorBytes);
                blendModeColorStreamBitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(colorStreamBuffer);
                blendModeColorStreamImageView.setImageBitmap(blendModeColorStreamBitmap);
            }
        });
        return 0;
    }
```

Jni/C++:

```
jbyteArray color_frame_buffer = NULL;
jbyteArray raw_frame_buffer = NULL;

        raw_frame_buffer = (jbyteArray)cb->env->GetObjectField(cb->video_stream_obj, cb->raw_buffer_dield_id);
        if(raw_frame_buffer == NULL)
        {
            ALOGE("Fail to get raw_frame_buffer field");
            return -1;
        }

        cb->env->SetByteArrayRegion(raw_frame_buffer,0, cb->raw_stream_buffer_size,(jbyte *)req.text + cb->raw_stream_buffer_offset);
        cb->env->SetDoubleField(cb->video_stream_obj,cb->raw_fps_dield_id,video_stream_info.fps);
        cb->env->SetDoubleField(cb->video_stream_obj,cb->raw_jitter_dield_id,video_stream_info.jitter);

        color_frame_buffer = (jbyteArray)cb->env->GetObjectField(cb->video_stream_obj,cb->color_buffer_dield_id);
        if(color_frame_buffer == NULL)
        {
            ALOGE("Fail to get color_frame_buffer field");
            return -1;
        }

        rgba_buffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(cb->color_stream_buffer_size);
        if(rgba_buffer == nullptr)
        {
            ALOGE("Not enough memory field.");
            return -1;
        }
        memset(rgba_buffer, 0, cb->color_stream_buffer_size);
        Yuv422ToRgba(cb->color_video_width, cb->color_video_height, (uint8_t*)req.text + cb->color_stream_buffer_offset, rgba_buffer);
        cb->env->SetByteArrayRegion(color_frame_buffer,0, cb->color_stream_buffer_size, (jbyte *)rgba_buffer);
        cb->env->CallIntMethod(cb->obj,cb->on_frame_function_id,cmd,jpath_obj, raw_frame_buffer, color_frame_buffer);
```

YuvToRgba

```
void Yuv422ToRgba(int width, int heigth, uint8_t *yuv_buffer, uint8_t* rbga_buffer)
{
    int pixel_size = width*heigth;
    uint32_t *pixel_ptr = (uint32_t *)rbga_buffer;
    uint8_t *y1_byte, *y2_byte, *u_byte, *v_byte;
    uint8_t r_byte, g_byte, b_byte;

    for (int y_itr = 0; y_itr  < pixel_size * 2; y_itr += 4)
    {
        u_byte = yuv_buffer + y_itr;
        y1_byte = yuv_buffer + y_itr + 1;
        v_byte = yuv_buffer + y_itr + 2;
        y2_byte = yuv_buffer + y_itr + 3;

        r_byte = *y1_byte + 1.4023 * (*v_byte-128.0);
        g_byte = *y1_byte - 0.3456 * (*u_byte-128.0) - 0.7145 * (*v_byte-128.0);
        b_byte = *y1_byte + 1.771 * (*u_byte-128.0);
        *pixel_ptr = 0x00000000 | r_byte << 16 | g_byte << 8 | b_byte;
        pixel_ptr ++;

        r_byte = *y2_byte + 1.4023 * (*v_byte-128.0);
        g_byte = *y2_byte - 0.3456 * (*u_byte-128.0) - 0.7145 * (*v_byte-128.0);
        b_byte = *y2_byte + 1.771 * (*u_byte-128.0);
        *pixel_ptr = 0x00000000 | r_byte << 16 | g_byte << 8 | b_byte;
        pixel_ptr ++;
    }
}
```